# Why doesn't fscanf scan the integer at the end of the line?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read in a file that contains multiple lines of the form:

```
www.someurl.com,timestamp
```

I am using the following code:

```
char url[256];
unsigned int timestamp;

// Read each line from the input file.
while(fscanf(inputfile, "%s,%d", url, &timestamp) == 2) {
    printf("%s was visited at %d\n", url, timestamp);
}
```

However, `fscanf` scans the entire line into the string, and does not scan the timestamp into the integer. I'm sure this is a very basic mistake, but I can't figure it out. Could someone please explain why this is, and how I can go about fixing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When processing `%s`, `fscanf` expects a whitespace terminated string, and it's greedy as well. So the entire line is read into the url.

You can specify the forbidden character set directly:

```
fscanf(inputfile, "%[^,],%d", url, &timestamp)
```

[Here's](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) a bit more data about `fscanf` variants and the format string.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'd never come across that syntax before but will be sure to remember it now.

Comment: @DanielGibbs, NP. Just be sure to guard against buffer overflows.

Comment: Will do. Valid domains can only have a maximum length of 256 right? So I think I'm sorted. (Assuming I only have valid ones)

Comment: @DanielGibbs, I'm not sure about the maximum length of a url. But you can also specify a maximum length `%255[^,]` just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Even better! Thanks again.